# Beginner fatal error lkn1104 when running simple code

Tags: c++

I am getting:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file '\nexpdc\twalz$\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Debug\Mine.exe'

when running the following for class:

```
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int age;
    cout << "What is your age?" ;

    cin >> age ;
    cout << age ;

    return 0 ;
}
```

What is wrong? Any assistance would be great. I am using Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Express.

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Do you have a copy of this program already running during the build?

Answer (score 3):

First of all this is not an error while running your program - it is an error while **linking**. Linking is a phase that happens after compilation but before running the program. Most often you see this error if visual studio can not open the executable for writing and this usually happens because you have the executable running while linking. Check if there is an instance of your program running and if there is, terminate it and try again.